# Setting Powershell prompt from within script

Tags: powershell

I've got an initialisation script that sets a couple of variables for later use.  The last line defines a "prompt" function, which I hoped would change my prompt, as an indication that the initialization had been done.  The variables get set, so it's not running as a sub-process, but my prompt stays stubbornly at "PS ".  What's going wrong?

Here's the script, with two versions of the function I've tried

```
$II_SYSTEM = "F:\Apps\Ingres92"
$env:PATH = "$II_SYSTEM\ingres\bin;$II_SYSTEM\ingres\utility;$env:PATH"
$env:LIB = "$II_SYSTEM\ingres\lib;$env:LIB"
$INCLUDE = "$II_SYSTEM\ingres\files;$INCLUDE"

function prompt{"PS $PWD IX>"}
function prompt{write-output ("PS $PWD IX>") -nonewline}
```

Thanks.

Comment: if you want the initialization to always happen, do it in the profile. Changing prompt there definitely works. See Get-Help about_Profiles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call your script file with dot-source:

```
. .\myscript.ps1
```

This make available variables and functions created at script level to global scope.
Or change the script like this:

```
function global:prompt{"PS $PWD IX>"}
function global:prompt{write-output ("PS $PWD IX>") -nonewline}
```

and call it normally.

Comment: So simple when you know how!

Comment: So simple when you know how!  Thanks.